# Please check this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> Great works of art, such as the Mona Lisa and Whistler's Mother, can be deceptive their simplicity.

Why is *can be + adj* followed with a *noun*?

And because of that I'm not really sure about the meaning. Does the person want to say that art can be simple yet remarkable?

Comment: It should say "... can be deceptive **in** their simplicity". It doesn't make sense as is.

Comment: @nnnnnn Now I understand, but what about the meaning?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. *Deceptive simplicity* and *deceptive in its simplicity* are common expressions meaning that the thing in question may seem simple, but despite that is actually remarkable or important. A painting or a machine, for example, may be constructed using simple techniques or components, but the combined effect may be remarkable. (Of course many simple things "are* unremarkable.)

Comment: @nnnnnn It's all clear now, thank you